# How to understand isset in codeigniter(php)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey I'm new to php and codeigniter. I know codeigniter has an  isset function.
what does the following code mean? Can someone please help

```
<?php echo isset($error) ? $error : ''; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, you can echo variable like that. So what is your question?

Comment: <?php echo isset($error) ? $error : ''; ?> what does it mean

Comment: To me that just says "If $error is set, echo it, if not, echo nothing".  I'm confused as to what information you are looking for.

Comment: $error is not set but code working properly

Comment: in controller class i write $data['error'] = 'your input is invalid';

Comment: <?php echo isset($error) ? $error : ''; ?> what does it mean

Comment: You need to give a more detailed example of your code and what you're trying to achieve. Followed by the specific error when you do.  The first example you gave is just a perfectly well-formed ternary operator that should do exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: what does it mean ? in this code

Comment: <?php echo isset($error) ? $error : ''; ?>

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 2):

isset is a php function, you can use it without CodeIgnitor, but it basically checks to see if the variable has been set yet.

```
$someVariable = 'This variable has been set';

var_dump(isset($someVariable)); // True
var_dump(isset($anotherVariable)); // False
```

the `?` and `:` parts tell PHP what to do. It's called a ternary operator, and can be thought as as a short `if` statement:

```
echo isset($someVariable) ? 'set' : 'not set';
```

is the same as:

```
if (isset($someVariable)) {
    echo 'set';
} else {
    echo 'not set';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary